# Handle error converting {null} to type system.Int32 in input json

Tags: .net, json, json.net

Platform : C#
IDE : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

I am new to Json and wondering on how to handle the error converting value {null} to type system.Int32 in an input. Any suggestion?

Comment: What libraries are you using to do your Json serialization?

Comment: @PauliØsterø according to the tags it's Json.net

Comment: @Nasreddine doh, need more coffee :)

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use replace your `Int32`s with their nullable counterpart using `int?` . You can find more about nullable types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to ignore null values.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourType>(jsonText, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: I believe this is the appropriate answer. I would prefer NOT to change my C# model just to be able to accept randomness that comes from an API.

Answer (score 0):

Same fix in other format in vb.net

```
Dim BE As New User_BE
Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings()
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
BE = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of User_BE)(json_str, settings)
```